# Using 'msdeploy' to sync a folder on a local IIS server with a remote IIS webserver

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I am trying to sync a folder on a local IIS server with a folder on a remote IIS server using msdeploy.exe.

I found some instructions at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/web-deploy-msdeploy-how-to-sync-a-folder/ which demonstrated how to do this with the command in the attached image. [example msdeploy command to sync folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLNYY.png)

My question is what is the 'ComputerName' value referring to? How do I find the 'ComputerName' of the destination server (or any server for that matter).

I tried following the instructions at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/web-deploy-msdeploy-how-to-sync-a-folder/ but was not sure how to determine the 'ComputerName' of my destination server.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-deployment-properties-for-a-target-environment#choosing-the-right-deployment-properties), there is a detailed description of this parameter, like this:

> If you're deploying to the remote agent service on the destination web server, you can specify the target computer name (for example, TESTWEB1 or TESTWEB1.fabrikam.net), or you can specify the remote agent endpoint (for example, http://TESTWEB1/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE). The deployment works the same way in each case. If you're deploying to the Web Deploy Handler on the destination web server, you should specify the service endpoint and include the name of the IIS website as a query string parameter (for example, https://STAGEWEB1:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=DemoSite).

Can you understand the explanation in this paragraph, or do you not know what remote server you are using?